# How to set default opening folder for Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, directory, default

How do I configure Nautilus to open at my Documents folder instead of my home folder?

I've scoured this site and found answers instructing users to edit the `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` file, replacing `%U` with the path to the desired default directory. I've edited all the variants of `nautilus.desktop` in the said directory, but none of the edits has an effect. I've checked all the files after editing them to make sure that I saved the edit effectively, and all look good to me.

I've edited every file to read as follows:

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/judy/Documents
```

I've also edited the `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` file, just to be sure, with no joy.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

Note: if I enter `nautilus /home/judy/Documents` from the command line, Nautilus properly opens in the desired directory.  Is there a simple way that I can configure an icon in the launcher bar to run this command and have the Nautilus icon that looks like a metal file drawer?

Thanks. I'm pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: Did you try a restart after making these changes?

Comment: Also, if you just run `nautilus --new-window /home/judy/Documents` in Terminal does it work as desired?

Comment: To my surprise, the way it used to work doesn' t anymore. WIll remove my answer, will post back if I find out why.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've edited the original nautilus desktop files in /usr/share/applications back to their default state.  I've copied the org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop file into my ~/.local/share/applications directory and used gedit to edit its Exec line. I've rebooted. I've run the source ~/.profile command. Sadly, still no joy. When I start nautilus from the launcher bar, it still starts in my home directory instead of in my documents directory.

Comment: Here is the contents of the file:[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/judy/Documents
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
DBusActivatable=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.14.2
etc... the web site doesn't let me add more chars.

Comment: @trinkner see my comment above, I am quite surprised myself, just tested it. There must be a change since 15.04. I will try tg find out how to set the defailt directory. The content of the Exec= line is ignored...

Comment: Bump. Is there any better answer to this?  If this is a bug, how do I report a bug to the developers?  (My apologies, but I don't know enough about programming in Ubuntu yet to contribute a fix myself.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is what worked for me on a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04:

(Worth noting that while on the UI the app is called "Files", under the hood it's still referred to as `nautilus`.)

1. Copy the right launcher to the right location:

   ```
   /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
   ```

   to

   ```
   /home/<YOURUSERNAME>/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Make the copy executable, either with:

   ```
   chmod +x /home/<YOURUSERNAME>/.local/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
   ```

   or by <kbd>right-clicking</kbd> the icon → *Properties* → *Permissions* tab → checkbox *Allow executing file as program*.
3. Edit the copy:

   - There are two lines that start with `Exec=`. Edit both lines so they look like this:

     ```
     Exec=nautilus --new-window /your/desired/directory
     ```

     Note that I removed the `%U` from the end of the line.
   - Deal with the `DBusActivatable` entry (thanks [L31N](https://askubuntu.com/a/753304/1157519)).

     Either assign a `false` value to it, or comment out the line, like this:

     ```
     # DBusActivatable=true
     ```

     I don't know know about any side effects of this latter step, I hope it's gonna be fine in the long run.
4. Either reboot or just log out of the session and log back in.

For me now it opens my directory both when called via the dash and when clicked in the dock.

Comment: That was helpful. In my case I don't use launcher, but have keys assigned like in windows explorer (Windows+E). Only thing I had to do, was edit key combination command adding desired folder. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to make the .desktop file executable: Step 2 can be removed.

Comment: To avoid needing to logout, instead make the initial copy to ~, and then edit the file, and then install it using `desktop-file-install --delete-original --dir="$HOME/.local/share/applications/" ~/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`. It will appear in your start menu immediately. This has the added benefit that (I think) this step will validate the file as it installs it.

Answer (score 5):

The file that is shown in unity-dash is not anymore `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` but `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`.

Changing the `Exec=` line in the file itself does not have any effect.
The problem is an entry `DBusActivatable=true` that makes the system to run nautilus via dbus. So the `Exec=` line is being ignored. Maybe it is possible to provide nautilus the desired directory through dbus (`/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Nautilus.service`) but I am not familiar with that system in detail.
For further information look here: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/DBusApplicationLaunching

A simple solution for me was to hide the gnome/dbus launcher-icon and make the old one visible again. So add the entry `NotShowIn=Unity;` to `/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` and comment it out in `nautilus.desktop`. There you can adjust the `Exec=` line with the desired directory.

```
(file: org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop)

[Desktop Entry]
NotShowIn=Unity;     # <--------------------------- add this line !
Name=files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
DBusActivatable=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.14.2
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=Window;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

#OnlyShowIn=Unity;    # <---------------- comment out this line !

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
#OnlyShowIn=Unity;    # <---------------- comment out this line !
```

```
(file nautilus.desktop)

[Desktop Entry]
#NotShowIn=Unity;     # <---------------- comment out this line !
Name=files
Comment=Access and organize files
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
Exec=nautilus --new-window /{DESIRED_DIRECTORY}     # <- adjust !
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.14.2
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=Window;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
```

Comment: @techraf Still no joy after editing the files. I'm confused why there are so many nautilus configuration files. What does each do? My system has `usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`, `usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`, and `usr/share/applications/nautilus-classic.desktop` and `usr/share/applications/nautilus-autorun-software.desktop`, and `usr/share/applications/nautilus-connect-server.desktop` and `usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop` and `usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

Comment: @trinkner
I do not know for what each file exactly is, but these are different launcher-icons for different uses. `nautilus-home.desktop` e.g. is used for the home-icon in the launcher (open it and look at the comment).  You can also create new icons for specific locations. You only have to copy nautilus.desktop and replace `%U` with the directory. To find it in the dash you have to make sure that there is no entry `NotShowIn=Unity`.

Comment: I succeeded in getting Nautilus to open to my desired folder by making the edits suggested by @techraf.  But after the edits, Nautilus continued to open at the default /home/user directory when launched  from a pinned launcher bar icon. To solve this, I renamed EVERY nautilus `.desktop` file in /usr/share/applications by appending `.backup` to the file name. I  appended `.backup` to the org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop file name. The one file I did not rename was `nautilus.desktop`, which I edited as suggested by @techraf.  Now the launcher icon correctly opens in my desired folder.

Comment: That didn't work either.  I'm on ubuntu 18 LTS.  This whole thing has been ridiculous. I've tried 30 different things, but I still can't click on a desktop folder and open it.  It's amazing to watch time go on and technology regress into uselessness. I thought opening inode/directories was a solved problem.  Maybe I'll wait till the next LTS.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me on **Ubuntu 22.10** with the somewhat *new* nautilus from gnome 43.

This is the original file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
# Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;nautilus;
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
Terminal=false
Type=Application
DBusActivatable=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-7z-compressed-tar;application/x-bzip;application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;application/x-compress;application/x-compressed-tar;application/x-cpio;application/x-gzip;application/x-lha;application/x-lzip;application/x-lzip-compressed-tar;application/x-lzma;application/x-lzma-compressed-tar;application/x-tar;application/x-tarz;application/x-xar;application/x-xz;application/x-xz-compressed-tar;application/zip;application/gzip;application/bzip2;application/vnd.rar;
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
Actions=new-window;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=nautilus --new-window
```

1. copy this to user config

> cp -rv /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications

> chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications

2. Enter text editor.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
# DBusActivatable=true
[Desktop Action new-window]
Exec=nautilus --new-window /path/to/your/preferred/directory
```

3. Restart or logout.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make this work for a while now. After a lot of frustration, stumbled on something that worked for me:

- changed all the "Exec" commands in all the [files that start with "nautilus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M89Q4.png)

  `Exec=nautilus-autorun-software /home/user/Desktop`
- deleted all existing ["Files" icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVWBQ.png) from my Desktop and
  `/home/user/.local/share/applications` 
  folder (had quiet a few of them due to past tries to solve this issue that did not work)
- changed 3 lines in /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop:

  `Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/user/Desktop
  DBusActivatable=false
  ...
  Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/john/Desktop/repos`

Note: the Exec command apear twice in org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop! one time at the very last line. changed both.

- restarted the computer
- started files from activities (Activities -> Type here to search... -> "Files")
  and it worked.

I added the Files icon to favorites (with right click -> add to favorites) and it opens the correct folder every time.

This is my org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop file after the change:

```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Files
   Comment=Access and organize files
   # Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or 
   localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
   Keywords=folder;manager;explore;disk;filesystem;
   Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/user/Desktop
   # Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon 
   file name)!
   Icon=org.gnome.Nautilus
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   DBusActivatable=false
   StartupNotify=true
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
   MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-7z-compressed;application/x-7z- 
   compressed-tar;application/x-bzip;application/x-bzip-compressed-tar;a$
   X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
   Actions=new-window;
   X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#af4853
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

   OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;

   [Desktop Action new-window]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/user/Desktop/repos
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simpler way:

- Create an empty file in your desktop.
- Open it with a text editor, such as gedit.
- Write the following lines:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name="Open Nautilus in custom folder"
  Exec="nautilus /path/to/custom/folder"
  Type=Application
  ```

Save it as `nautilus_custom.desktop`.
Open a terminal and run:

```
chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/nautilus_custom.desktop
```

Without quotes. Now you should be able to start Nautilus in you custom folder by double-clicking the file you've just created in your desktop.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really bad. *Never* have multiple `.desktop` files represent the same application in their main command. It will mess up the presence of nautilus in the launcher.