# Open folder by default in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Does anyone know how I can change the default open folder in Nautilus

How to let Nautilus open documents directory by default instead of home directory?

Comment: Sorry yes you are wright. I meant open the directory Documents instead of the home directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can

- use the methods described in the 'duplicate of' link,

  [How to set default opening folder for Nautilus file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706672/how-to-set-default-opening-folder-for-nautilus-file-manager)
- simply run the following command in a terminal window,

  ```
  nautilus --new-window ~/Documents
  ```
- you can use that command line in a desktop file and start Nautilus via that desktop file. If this is what you want, you can copy

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/Desktop
  ```

  and edit the line that starts with `Exec=`

  ```
  nano /home/vidar/Desktop/nautilus.desktop
  ```

  where you should use your actual user ID (which I guess is `vidar`).

  ```
  Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/vidar/Documents
  ```

  Give execute permissions to this file

  ```
  chmod ugo+x /home/vidar/Desktop/nautilus.desktop
  ```

  I think it will be called 'Files' on the desktop.

  Finally, use this modified desktop file (by double-clicking on its icon).

Comment: +1 though it seemed Op wanted nautilus to always open @ Documents. In that case put it in ~/.local/share/applications folder

Comment: You may be right @doug. Let us hope the OP will tell us exactly what he wants and what solution he selects :-)