# how to change 'nautilus's default directory path to a specific folder

Tags: nautilus

how to change 'nautilus's default directory path to a specific folder when it runs from terminal command? (i. e. :~$ nautilus (It opens default 'Home' folder). Changes made in /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop and in /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop files, still it opens the default home folder. (OS ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962296/open-folder-by-default-in-nautilus

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open Desktop

```
sudo nautilus Desktop
```

If you want to open root dir

```
sudo nautilus /
```

Specification is

```
sudo nautilus yout_dir
```

Comment: not like this. If I type the command in terminal (i. e. :~$ nautilus) it should open the Desktop/MyFiles/ folder. 
Changes made in /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop file as:
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U to Exec=nautilus --new-window Desktop/MyFiles/
After this change, while clicking the nautilus icon it directly opens the MyFiles folder. But when i use the terminal command it shows the default Home folder.