# How to change the default folder of 'Files' to "Starred"?

Tags: gui, 20.10

Is it possible to change the default location that 'Files' opens into? Currently, it opens the 'Home' directory, but I would like it to open the 'Starred' directory.

Thank you!

Comment: This is how I did it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302438/1157519

Comment: Is there a 'path' to the Starred folder? I couldn't find one. Currently, I have put everything I want starred into a single folder and used the method you referred to point to that folder, and it works! Thanks!

Comment: PS,  I edited the title of your question. Else, it is just a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/706672/how-to-set-default-opening-folder-for-nautilus-file-manager/1302438#1302438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default startup folder of nautilus by editing the `.desktop` launcher for Files, as [detailed in this anwser](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302438/1157519). It boils down to copying the system wide launcher to your private `.local/share/applications` folder, and then editing the copy in that local folder. Edit it such that the `Exec=` lines read like

```
Exec=nautilus starred:///
```

In contrast to what is indicated in the [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302438/1157519), you need to remove both `--new-window` and `%U` for this to work.

Users that wish to autostart in the "Recent" folder can supply `recent:///`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I did have to comment out `DBusActivatable=true` though. It did not work otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will remove that then from my answer, although for me it worked leaving it on (also on Ubu 20.10).

Comment: While this worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, whenever I start Nautilus by clicking on a folder on the Desktop (provided by the default gnome extension Desktop Icons NG), I get two windows: one with the starred, and one with the actual folder. Any clue how to work around that?