# How to open the "Starred" category in nautilus via terminal command

Tags: command-line, nautilus, xfce4-terminal

So in nautilus there is a starred category for the files you star. The home folder gets messy with all the things ive installed so ive starred my defualt folders such as "Desktop" and "documents" etc. I use special + E to run the command "Nautilus" to open files. Im looking to automatically open the "Starred" category instead. Any solutions? Is there a terminal command that would open nautilus in the starred section?

Comment: If the home folder is messy, that is because you allow it to be messy. Normally, no things are installed in the home folder by automated install procedures. For manual procedures, you can decide where you install.

Comment: yeah i know lol, i didnt say it wasnt my fault lol. This just seems easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the URI `starred:///` will open nautilus in the Starred category:

```
nautilus starred:///
```

Comment: Thank you haha. I tried a "nautilus starred" i just didnt know it needed the extra :/// thanks.

Comment: yeah im not an absoulte linux noob ive used it for a while just never done that specific stuff with nautilus lol. Thanks again haha.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Now I need *another* SO question, how do I replace the nautilus icon on the dock with one that opens in this location... ;-)

Comment: Aha, which is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706672/how-to-set-default-opening-folder-for-nautilus-file-manager