# Files opens to the Home directory

Tags: nautilus, icons

The Files icon use to open to show 'Previous, Home, Documents, etc' as shown in first image. It has now change to open directly to 'Home' as shown in second image. How do I change it back to look like the first image?
[image: first image][image: second image]. This may be a trivial question but as a newbie it has me stuck.

Comment: [This answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302438/1222991) should give you what you need 

Comment: Are you talking about this https://i.postimg.cc/zvKst4j6/Nautilus-Sidebar.png? Show sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar is missing in the second image from what I gather. Just enable it again in the the settings:

[image: Sidebar Checkbox]

Edit: Apparently, nautilus comes with slew of keyboard shortcuts. **F9** toggles the **sidebar**
[image: nautilus keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: I suggest adding the possibility to use the shortcut key, F9, to show/hide the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you! too easy. I'll know next time